# finding which program produces a log file

Tags: ubuntu, mutt, msmtp

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I have an email account configured on the terminal.

Probably a left-over from the time I tried to configure that account, I have some logs being printed to a file in my home directory a couple of times day.

An example of a log (one line, split here for readability):

```
28 12:36:02 host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on
  user=***@gmail.com from=***@gmail.com recipients=&&& smtpstatus=553
  smtpmsg='553 5.1.2 The recipient address <&&&> is not a valid RFC-5321 address. q65sm28155223wmd.6 - gsmtp'
  errormsg='recipient address &&& not accepted by the server' exitcode=EX_DATAERR
```

It is printed to `~/msmtp.log`

My question is how can I discover where does this printing comes from in order to kill it?

Solution:
The log was printed by msmtp itself. A quick look at the msmtp manfile showed that the configuration file is ~/.msmtprc . I edited this file to change the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably written by [mstmp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) itself.